# File path with double slashes python

Tags: python, windows, path

I want to be able to get the file path of a python executable:

```
import os,sys
path=os.getcwd()+'\\'+sys.argv[0]
```

I want to check if path is a valid path with os.path.isfile().However this doesnt work as the path variable returned has single slashes. Python for some reason cant detect paths with single slashes. How can I make all the single slashes() double slashes(\).I want to make `C:\path\to\file` to `C:\\path\\to\\file`. python can't use the .replace() for single quotes so what other way can I get a path with double slashes

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: You don't want to make it `\\ ` and I'm not sure why you think you do.

Comment: I think you just need `__file__`. `path=os.getcwd()+'\\'+sys.argv[0]` is wrong, what if the tool is run from another path, or with full path?

Comment: or (works with cxfreeze & py2exe): `script_file = sys.executable if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ) else __file__
`

Comment: how about pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

With no other caveats, those slashes are read as escape characters. You can, for example, use the raw prefix (i.e. r'\' instead of '\') for replace as a fix.

That's still being inefficient though - your code will break on different OSes this way - you should use os.path module's path operations instead.